# ng-repeat ($last) element with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
var dataList = [{Id:1,Name: "xyz",Select: true},
                {Id:2,Name: "PQR",Select : false }];
var headerList = [{"ID","Name","null"}]
```

i got this value from server side i can not make any changes in this array list.

My html code is

```
<table class= "table table-bordered">
    <thead>
       <tr ng-repeat="header in headerList">
          <td ng-if="!$last">
             {{header}}
          </td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
         <td ng-repeat="value in  data" ng-if="!$last">
             {{value}}
         </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't want to generate "Select" column. code works propely , but when bordered class applies on table one blank column is display i.e "Select"

so that how can i remove this blank column in html DOM ?

Comment: I think something wrong  in the headerList = [{"ID","Name","null"}]. The object has only properties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to write

```
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <td ng-if="!$last" ng-repeat="header in headerList">
             {{header}}
          </td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
```

instead of this

```
<thead>
   <tr ng-repeat="header in headerList">
      <td ng-if="!$last">
         {{header}}
      </td>
   </tr>
</thead>
```